# Custom validation triggering required

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive

```
app.directive('postcode', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (val) {
                    var regex = /^(([gG][iI][rR] {0,}0[aA]{2})|((([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][0-9][a-hjkstuwA-HJKSTUW])|([a-pr-uwyzA-PR-UWYZ][a-hk-yA-HK-Y][0-9][abehmnprv-yABEHMNPRV-Y]))) {0,}[0-9][abd-hjlnp-uw-zABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$/,
                        valid = regex.test(val);

                    if(valid) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('postcode', true);
                        return val;
                    }
                    else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('postcode', false);   
                        return undefined;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

on a field that is also required

Whilst the required bit works seamlessly (yay!)
the postcode one works, but also shows the required error message as well as invalid

(for some reason copy/pasting dom elements causes an error but doesnt say what)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, in my `setValidity` call i was using a keyword that angular uses already which as per its rule was equating to valid

I've as yet been able to find a nice list of definitive rules that are shipped with angular by default

Answer (score 0):

May you have a fiddle or plunkr?

How do you see the required error message?
May your condition for show it is just wrong and your directive works?!

Your directives seems nice.